# Is it more efficient to add shadows to an image programmatically or have them already on the image in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am loading a view controller with about 6 buttons that have a preset image already defined- I am curious as to whether it's better (faster/more efficient) to have a function that adds the shadow onto each item or to have the shadow already on the image so it is already there when the image is assigned to the button. The buttons for now have the image set in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to add a shadow to an image beforehand. A shadow has to use the multiply blend mode (the destination is multiplied by the shadow), but the rest of the image needs to use alpha blending (the destination is multiplied by the inverse of an image's mask, and added to the image, multiplied by its mask).

You can emulate this by having a shadow with partial transparency, but that is a different color:

`shadow * α + destination * (1 - α)`

instead of

`shadow * destination`

If that looks good enough, then yes, it's more efficient. But it won't matter on today's (or yesterday's!) hardware.

Comment: The designer designed the icons (sorry should have been more clear) with shadows - for example a camera icon has a shadow on it. But they were suggesting I use the non shadow icon and program the shadow onto it. Just wasn't sure which way was more efficient

Comment: You should tell the designer that you can't use premultiplied alpha blending, which won't allow for baked-in shadows.

Answer (score -1):

Short:
Energy wise it's more efficient to have the shadow on the image as you need to load it anyway, thus saving the extra drawing for a shadow.

Previous longer answer that seemingly wasn't understandable:

Everything that doesn‘t need extra cpu cycles is better. Especial in your case where the bitmap will take the same amount of memory in the end. It would be different if the data to load for the image would be considerably bigger.

This consideration is the reason why watchOS apps use precalculated images for animations, instead of drawing animation during runtime.

Comment: So are you saying it is better to program the shadow upon view load?

Comment: This is more of a “GPU cycles” situation.

Comment: No. ViewDidLoad is fine as it is run once and you don't need to respond manually to dynamic view changes. Energy wise it's more efficient to have the shadow on the image as you need to load it anyway, thus saving the extra drawing for a shadow. That was you question.